# Consurrent consumers per topic in spring-rabbit

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

Can spring-rabbit be made to support multiple concurrent consumers on a single topic?

Here are the details

My system uses manual ack mode with a topic exchange via spring-rabbit (Spring 4.0.6).  The pattern is as follows:

- Message comes into ChannelAwareMessageListener
- A factory method generates an appropriate worker and passes in a reference to the channel
- If the worker successfully processes the message, the message is Ack'd
- If the worker is unsuccessful or an exception happens, the message is Nack'd and sent into a dead letter queue for later processing

Since some of these workers can take a fair bit of time to complete their IO-bound processing, I need to be able to set a higher number of concurrent consumers.

After some testing, however, I've noticed that there are times when several consumers are receiving the same message.  Sure enough, a look at the documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html#setConcurrentConsumers-int-), confirms my finding:

> Do not raise the number of concurrent consumers for a topic, unless vendor-specific setup measures clearly allow for it. With regular setup, this would lead to concurrent consumption of the same message, which is hardly ever desirable.

My questions are as follows:

1. What the heck does "unless vendor-specific setup measures clearly allow for it" mean?  Is there a patch/version/configuration or Rabbit that supports this?
2. I can easily write code on the client that prevents a message from being processed if it's already being processed by another worker.  What, then, do I do with this message?  Send nack?  Ignore it?  What happens if I nack and then the worker which is actually processing the message sends an ack some time later?  Will an exception be thrown?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning you mentionned is about JMS not RabbitMQ. Have a look at the [Spring RabbitMQ documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html#setConcurrentConsumers-int-). The documentation does not contain this warning.

Once a message is delivered to a queue (whatever the exchange type), it can be taken by a consumer/worker **only once** at a time (assuming no issue).

If you receive the same message twice there is somewhere an issue:

- the message is nacked and requeued
- the channel/connection are closed on the client side
- there is network issue and Rabbit requeue automaticly the message (the channel/connection are closed on the server and on the client side)

For the last two points you should get some errors messages.

Note that this point is in my opinion unnecessary and may explain the issue:

> - A factory method generates an appropriate worker and passes in a
>     reference to the channel

The `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` already uses an `Executor`. As you are using your own executor there is maybe an issue between the spring-amqp channels pool (if you use any) and your executors eg. the channel is closed because spring-amqp believe it is not used anymore.

Instead of spawning your own thread, process the message on the same thread of the current `ChannelAwareMessageListener#onMessage` thread.